# Python logging to MemoryHandler initialised in configuration file

Tags: python, logging, configuration-files

I am trying to add the python `MemoryHandler` into a logging configuration file. I am using a similar structure to a file handler that worked previously. I am a bit confused as to the error I am receiving and can't figure out what I am missing in order to get the logging to go to memory. The necessary information has been included below.In assistance would be greatly appreciated.

**log_settings.conf**

```
[loggers]
keys=root

[handlers]
keys=memHandler, consoleHandler

[formatters]
keys=fileFormatter, consoleFormatter

[logger_root]
level=DEBUG
handlers=memHandler, consoleHandler

[handler_consoleHandler]
class=StreamHandler
level=INFO
formatter=consoleFormatter
args=(sys.stdout,)

[handler_memHandler]
class=handlers.MemoryHandler
formatter=fileFormatter
args=(10, DEBUG, '%(logfilename)s')

[formatter_fileFormatter]
format=[%(asctime)s] [%(levelname)8s] --- (%(filename)15s:%(lineno)4s) %(message)s
datefmt=%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S

[formatter_consoleFormatter]
format=%(message)s
```

**Error Traceback**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\BuildScript\proj_tcl\blr_sbz\blr_sbz_build.py", line 22, in <module>
    main(args.jenkins, args.revision, args.jenkins_num)
  File "E:\BuildScript\proj_tcl\blr_sbz\blr_sbz_build.py", line 10, in main
    build(jenkins, revision, jenkins_num)
  File "../scripts\build.py", line 17, in build
    logging.info('Starting the FGPA build script')
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1870, in info
    root.info(msg, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1301, in info
    self._log(INFO, msg, args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1437, in _log
    self.handle(record)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1447, in handle
    self.callHandlers(record)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1509, in callHandlers
    hdlr.handle(record)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 858, in handle
    self.emit(record)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\logging\handlers.py", line 1213, in emit
    self.flush()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\logging\handlers.py", line 1289, in flush
    self.target.handle(record)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'handle'
```

**build.py**

```
logging.config.fileConfig('../scripts/logging/log_settings.conf', defaults={'logfilename': '../scripts/logging/log.log'})
logging.info('Starting the FGPA build script')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this configuration file instead:

```
[loggers]
keys=root

[handlers]
keys=memHandler, consoleHandler

[formatters]
keys=fileFormatter, consoleFormatter

[logger_root]
level=DEBUG
handlers=memHandler

[handler_consoleHandler]
class=StreamHandler
level=INFO
formatter=consoleFormatter
args=(sys.stdout,)

[handler_memHandler]
class=handlers.MemoryHandler
formatter=fileFormatter
args=(10, DEBUG)
target=consoleHandler

[formatter_fileFormatter]
format=[%(asctime)s] [%(levelname)8s] --- (%(filename)15s:%(lineno)4s) %(message)s
datefmt=%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S

[formatter_consoleFormatter]
format=%(message)s
```

Note that you shouldn't include the `consoleHandler` in the list of handlers for the root logger. Also, you need to set the target using a `target=` line, and it needs to reference the key for the target handler. Use the following to configure:

```
logging.config.fileConfig('logging.ini')
```